# Passing primitive data types by reference in Objective C

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, pass-by-reference

I have a C++ function which I call from Objective C.I need to pass variables by reference to the C++ function.But I get the following error in xcode - "Expected ';', ',' or ')' before '&' token in foo.h"

Function declaration in "foo.h"

```
#ifdef __cplusplus

extern "C"
{
#endif  

NSString * LLtoUTM(double Lat,double Long,double &UTMNorthing, double &UTMEasting); 

#ifdef __cplusplus  
}
#endif
```

Function call in test_viewcontroller.m

```
double UTM_x;
double UTM_y;
UTMzone = [[NSString alloc] init];    
UTMzone = (NSString *) LLtoUTM(latitude,longitude,UTM_y,UTM_x);
```

Can anyone tell me what is wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the file to be test_viewcontroller.mm.

You told it to compile as an Objective-C file, which doesn't understand references. '.mm' means Objective-C++, which can mix the Obj-C and C++ together like what you're attempting to do.

Comment: @Joshua - I tried that.But it affects other obj-C code I have written in test_viewcontroller.m.(I get 50 errors and I do not have the patience to debug it).Is there any equivalent to C++ pass by reference in objective c?

Comment: You shouldn't get errors unless you did something screwy...but the closest you'll get is your standard C pass the address in and deref it on the other side

Comment: On another note, [[NSString alloc] autorelease]; is completely wrong. alloc/init should never be seperated.

Comment: @Joshua - I debugged it and got it fixed! So now I have a .mm file and yet I get the error.Any idea if I got the syntax wrong?

Comment: I would need more context, are you sure that header isn't included in any other m or c files?

Comment: I got that error fixed! But now I get an error because of multiple includes of a file.I have used #import rather than #include everywhere.I think I need to create new post since it is a different issue.

Comment: I got the header include error fixed too!! Problem was that I had included a "globalvar.h" in 2 (lets say a.mm and b.mm) files of which only b.mm has mixed c++ and obj-c code.So I changed the extension of the other a.mm file to a.m.This worked for me!

Answer (score 0):

You simply cannot do this in plain Objective-C — because references don't exist in C. They're a C++ feature. So you have to use Objective-C++, which basically means changing your Objective-C files' extensions to ".mm".